# If I buy a costume in Tiny Tower, will all of my bitizens be able to wear it?

Tags: tiny-tower

Suppose I want to buy the pumpkin costume in Tiny Tower.

[image: pumpkin]

Can I then use this costume on any of my bitizens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes you can!** Once you pay the Bux to buy the costume, it remains unlocked and available to any bitizen you have in your tower.

I purchased the Astronaut costume for my bitizen whose dream job was the Planetarium, and have since put the other two Planetarium-dream-job bitizens in the same costume at no additional charge.